# How I Call another page in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a page razor inside a folder, I want to call a view outside this folder in .net core.

[image]

I am in 'MyList.cshtml ' and I want to add a tag to call 'Error'.
like this  `<a asp-page="./Error"> Error </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `<a asp-page="../Error"> Error </a>`

You use `..` to go to the parent.

`.` means the current folder.